# Curl Not Working on server but Works in Localhost

Tags: codeigniter, curl

I have been battling with this issue for a very long time. I have a code segment that uses curl to send/receive data/information. Am working with Codeigniter.
the problem is that it works fine on my localhost, but when i upload to my cPanel, the curl segment does not return any value.
My code:

```
<?php
$url = "http://remote-domain.com/";
       $fields = array(
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password,
            'source' => $sender,
            'message' => $message);
 $this->load->library('curl');
 return $result = $this->curl->simple_get($url, $fields);
?>
```

It works fine on localhost, but does not work when I upload to my server.
Any Help Please?

Comment: Check the priveleges account that is running your server vs the account you are using on localhost

Comment: What privilege? You mean file permissions?

Comment: Have you checked to error log?

Comment: More than likely you haven't installed cURL and all of its dependencies on your server.

Comment: Toni, I mean account permissions.. Are you running the server as the same user.  Also Willem's response sounds likely as well

Comment: I have cURL installed. Here is my server phpinfo: 
cURL support   enabled
cURL Information   7.24.0

Comment: @user20232359723568423357842364, there is no error found in the log

Comment: Funny thing..i have exactly the opposite as a problem. my stuff work well on my ftp but don't on my localhost, did you find an answer? maybe it can help me. Thanks

Comment: @Peter. I was able to solve by opening the port in from my server. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18092405/curl-not-working