# cURL not working

Tags: php, curl

I have been having some issue using a php cURL script. It worked fine on my localhost, but it does not work on my server. My server can successfully execute other curl script except this one. 
 This is the result of `print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));` from my server:

```
Array ( [url] => http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/bulksms/bulksms 
        [content_type] => 
        [http_code] => 0 
        [header_size] => 0 
        [request_size] => 0 
        [filetime] => -1 
        [ssl_verify_result] => 0 
        [redirect_count] => 0 
        [total_time] => 15.00012 
        [namelookup_time] => 0.000145 
        [connect_time] => 0 
        [pretransfer_time] => 0 
        [size_upload] => 0 
        [size_download] => 0 
        [speed_download] => 0 
        [speed_upload] => 0 
        [download_content_length] => -1 
        [upload_content_length] => -1 
        [starttransfer_time] => 0 
        [redirect_time] => 0 
        [certinfo] => Array ( ) 
        [primary_ip] => xx.xx.xx.xx 
        [primary_port] => 8080 
        [local_ip] => 
        [local_port] => 0 
        [redirect_url] => )
```

Here is the result of `print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));` from my localhost:

```
Array ( [url] => http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/bulksms/bulksms 
        [content_type] => text/html;charset=UTF-8 
        [http_code] => 200 
        [header_size] => 141 
        [request_size] => 178 
        [filetime] => -1 
        [ssl_verify_result] => 0 
        [redirect_count] => 0 
        [total_time] => 0.89 
        [namelookup_time] => 0 
        [connect_time] => 0 
        [pretransfer_time] => 0 
        [size_upload] => 0 
        [size_download] => 4 
        [speed_download] => 4 
        [speed_upload] => 0 
        [download_content_length] => 4 
        [upload_content_length] => 0 
        [starttransfer_time] => 0.89 
        [redirect_time] => 0 
        [certinfo] => Array ( ) 
        [primary_ip] => xx.xx.xx.xx 
        [primary_port] => 8080 
        [local_ip] => 127.0.0.1 
        [local_port] => 3925 
        [redirect_url] => )
```

What could be the cause, and how do I fix this?

Comment: What's `curl_error($ch)` say?

Comment: As far as I can tell the diff between those curl_getinfo's is: [local_ip] not being set on your live server that is not working correctly.

Comment: @anq : curl_error($ch); does not return any error. It shows a blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

port 8080 is blocked by your hosting provider. this is especially the case with shared hosting

Comment: This worked. I had to open port 8080 on the server firewall. Thanks! :)