# cURL request work fine on server but wont work on my localhost:8080

Tags: php, apache, curl, ssl

I create a process that log me in my account of #########.com. It work like a charm when I put it on my FTP.

**This is the problem** :

I have an apache local server set on my machine (easyPHP) on localhost:8080.
I have also an IIS server set on my machine at the port --> localhost:80.

My cURL request don't work. This is my code:

```
$lien = 'https://#########.com/login';
$postfields = array( 
    'username' => 'xxx',
    'password' => 'xxx'
);


$path_cookie = 'connexion.txt';
if (!file_exists(realpath($path_cookie))) touch($path_cookie);

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $lien);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath($path_cookie));

$return = curl_exec($curl);
echo($return);
echo 'error:' . curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
}
```

**Firstly:** Yes I have cURL install on my server, I did some other cURL request between my apache server and my IIS server and everything work fine.

**Secondly:** The file "connexion.txt" is well create, BUT empty.

**Thirdly:** The echo of ($return) response nothing, and on my server the response is "*Object moved to here.*"

**Fourthly:** Yes i read this topic, but didn't help me a lot..

> [cURL not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18092405/curl-not-working)

**Finally:** When I try to debug the cURL request the error is:

> error:SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Can anyone help me please? I'll stay here to answer comment/test/debug/answer etc.

Thanks !

Comment: you're using ssl with a self-signed certificate, probably, or haven't provided curl with the associated CA stuff so that it can validate your cert.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're most likely not using a certificate at all so either use http or try using

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);`

Answer (score 3):

It's not a good practice to set "CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST" false.

I recommed you to download the CA root certificate bundle and tell PHP where to find it.

1. You can find it to [download here](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html).
2. Download the .pem and save it where your PHP installation can access
   it.
3. Add to your php.ini the file location: `curl.cainfo="C:\Xamp\php\cacert.pem"`
4. Restart your server]

Job is done, safely.

---

Font: https://snippets.webaware.com.au/howto/stop-turning-off-curlopt_ssl_verifypeer-and-fix-your-php-config/

Comment: Finally a good solution without disabling the verification. Thanks!